# Guard Malloc doesn't work

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, debugging, profiling

I'm experimenting with different profiling options that Xcode provides, but when I enabling **Guard Malloc** option in **Diagnostics** tab and trying to run, I'm getting this error with immediate crash:

```
dyld: could not load inserted library: /usr/lib/libgmalloc.dylib
```

And it is right, `/usr/lib/` doesn't contain this library. I've located it in:

```
Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/lib/
```

So I've created link, and started **Command Line Tool** (just to be sure, because it apparently part of MacOS SDK), enabled Guard Malloc again but the problem remains.
I don't quite get where is a problem: does it new Xcode 4.3 inadvertence, problem with my system or planned decision by Apple to replace it with something else (maybe **Instruments**)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I got stuck by this too. From an apple list:

http://prod.lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2012/Feb/msg00197.html

> That's a known issue that's being investigated. I think that you may be able to work around it by installing the 10.7.3 combo installer

Which means you need to download the combo installer from: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1484?

I'm trying it now to make sure it works, but the person on the mailing list said it worked.

Comment: I have run into this too, although only on one of my Macs. (I'm not sure what the difference is. I've upgraded both of them on roughly the same path.) Installing the 10.7.4 combo updater did *not* help.

Comment: That is using the 10.7.4 updater?  http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1524 I haven't tried it, since I haven't run into the issue again yet.

Comment: Still broken on OS X 10.8, Xcode 4.5.2. I wish Apple would get their act together.

Answer (score 10):

on device or simulator?

According to http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MallocDebug.html

> You can use this option both Mac apps and also for iPhone applications running in the **simulator**.

Answer (score 0):

Problem came up again recently, combo update didn't helped (libgmalloc.dylib was in place).

New solution was to Repair Disk Permissions in Disk Utility:
[image: Disk Utility interface]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can't enable Guard Malloc when debugging directly on a device (at least iPad in my case), even when running the latest and greatest versions of everything. Running still works in the simulator though.